# Search last Four Digits of a column data in elastic search

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to search based on last four digits of a credit card number by using elastic search. Similar to sql LIKE. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What have you done? Please show your research results or some of your code! Through that, the SO-Community could provide better help!

Comment: TL;DR: you can't with [lucene syntax](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard Searches). Do a search on querying elasticsearch with regex. Founding the doc is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a wildcard/regex search (suggested in the comments) for characters at the end of a string would be extremely inefficient.

Instead you should:

1. reverse the string in your analyser
2. search the string using a prefix search

So, `123456789`would be indexed as `987654321` - then you'd also reverse your search term `6789` to be `9876` and do a prefix search of `9876` against `987654321`.

To set this up in Elasticsearch, it's simpler than it sounds:

Create the index and define a new analyser that will reverse the data when it's stored:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/test'

curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test' -d '{
    "analysis": {
       "analyzer": {
            "suffix_analyzer": {
                "filter": ["lowercase", "reverse"],
                "tokenizer": "keyword",
                "type": "custom"}
      }
   }
}'
```

Reference the analyser in your mapping:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/test/creditcard/_mapping" -d' {
    "creditcard" : {
      "properties": {
          "cardnumber":{"type" : "string", "analyzer" : "suffix_analyzer"}
        }
    }
}'
```

post some data (note that the cardnumber **isn't** reversed):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test/creditcard' -d'
{
   "cardnumber": "1234567890"
 }'
```

And then match_phrase_prefix to query the data:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/test/creditcard/_search?pretty' -d '{
 "query": { "match_phrase_prefix": { "cardnumber" : "7890"} }
}'
```

you should then get your data back:

```
{
 "took" : 38,
 "timed_out" : false,
 "_shards" : {
   "total" : 5,
   "successful" : 5,
   "failed" : 0
 },
 "hits" : {
   "total" : 1,
   "max_score" : 0.30685282,
   "hits" : [ {
     "_index" : "test",
     "_type" : "creditcard",
     "_id" : "AUxpxo4tY42JLXs1QAbE",
     "_score" : 0.30685282,
     "_source":
{
  "cardnumber": "1234567890"
}
```